# How to add a virtualhost in apache to point into a spring REST API deployed on Tomcat

Tags: spring, apache, tomcat, virtualhost, mod-jk

I have a rest API (backapp) which is deployed on a Tomcat server.
I have an angular frontend which is also deployed on the same Tomcat server.

And I need to add virtualhosts to apache (httpd) mounted to my two tomcat apps. I use JKMount in httpd.conf file

My Tomcat serves on 8080 my backapp andfrontapp

```
...
webapps
--> frontapp
--> backapp
...
```

The virtualhost for the frontend app works fine : (www.myhost.com/frontapp)

```
<virtualhost myhost:80>
    ServerName www.myhost.com
    ServerAlias myhost.com
    JkMount /frontapp/* ajp13
</virtualhost>
```

But the virtual host for rest API (backend) not working (www.myhost.com/backapp) got 404 error

```
<virtualhost myhost:80>
    ServerName www.myhost.com
    ServerAlias myhost.com
    JkMount /backapp/* ajp13
</virtualhost>
```

This is the structure of my backend :

```
backapp
|-- META-INF
|   |-- MANIFEST.MF
|   `-- maven
|       `-- compay
|           `-- backapp
|               |-- pom.properties
|               `-- pom.xml
`-- WEB-INF
    |-- classes
    |   |-- config.properties
    |   |-- logback.xml
    |   `-- company
    |       `-- contentpkg
    |           |-- AppInitializer.class
    |           |-- configuration
    |           |   |-- (classes)

    |           |-- controller
    |           |   |-- (classes)
    |           `-- model
    |               |-- (classes)

    `-- lib
        |-- commons-io-2.5.jar
        |-- commons-logging-1.2.jar
        |-- .....
```

Thanks

Comment: virtualhost is used for defining the domain name. in your case www.myhost.com. if you define two times I think apache should stop working but in your case probably first configuration works and second ignored. you should use proxypass here is detailed explanation https://tecadmin.net/setup-apache-as-reverse-proxy-for-tomcat/

Comment: @özkanpakdil  Right, thanks for the hint, works fine with proxy module.

Answer (score 0):

You could define both `JkMount`s in the same virtual host:

```
<virtualhost myhost:80>
    ServerName www.myhost.com
    ServerAlias myhost.com
    JkMount /frontapp/* ajp13
    JkMount /backapp/* ajp13
</virtualhost>
```

As you were told in comments, probably the problem was that there were two virtual host mappings using the same definition, and neither was a problem of the `mod_jk` configuration